# Promiscuous mode in LrWpanNetDevice NS3

Tags: pcap, ns-3, sniffer, promiscuous-mode

I have a network of Lrwpan  devices in NS3 and I want to make some nodes operate as sniffers. I enabled promiscuous mode in PCAP files but I want also to process the information that are contained in these packets. How should I get the actual content of the packet in NS3 so that I can do some calculations?
For example, if A -- B -- C is my topology and B is in RX/TX range of A and C, I want to enable B sniff packets of neighbors. Is this possible to do it in NS3? I don't want to see packets only in pcap file.

Edit: I found the SetPromiscuousMode() from MAC layer in Netdevice and enters promiscuous mode. However, is not able to send any packet, just receives. I want to enable TX and RX packets. Is that possible?

Comment: You may want to ask this on a sister site like Super User or networkengineering.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Do you want to: (a) only sniff packets; or (b) intercept packets and then transmit the changed packet instead of the original packet?

Comment: I want the (b). Sniff packets, do some changes and transmit the packet to my neighbours